# Split strings inside double quotes to array

Tags: powershell

Given a string, where each path is quoted inside a double quotes, how do I split it into an array with each item is the literal substrings inside the double quotes. For example:

```
$input=read-host "input"; $input.Split(" ")
```

With input string of `"D:\Path1\file1.txt" "D:\Path2\some [ weird, name.txt""D:\thispath\is_not_separated_by_space_after_quote.txt"`, it would split the string as long as it found space, not quotes-aware (don't think that's a word though). I'm expecting an output like this,

```
D:\Path1\file1.txt
D:\Path2\some [ weird, name.txt
D:\thispath\is_not_separated_by_space_after_quote.txt
```

without the double quotes. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you thot about  - [1] getting only one dir per `$Read-Host` call? and then looping until the use gives you a blank? ///// [2] using the directory picker dialog that windows uses? this ... FolderBrowserDialog Class (System.Windows.Forms) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Yeah, [1] would require too many user interaction, and I try to avoid that. [2] that works in some cases, but can't achieve what I'm to do, that is to drag and drop files into terminal from multiples different directories, while reduce the needs of user interactions.

Comment: allowing any user input and insisting on typing it in ... is formula for errors. [*grin*] user input otta be restricted to easily controlled methods when possible. ///// however, dealing with the problems that your choice will give you ... is your problem. if you don't mind it, then it is OK. [*grin*]

Comment: (Also @Tomek.) Do not assign any value to [`$Input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input)! `$Input` is an [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED
This is approach for people who do not like using regex, but I believe it should work here.

```
$input.Replace('""','" "').replace('" "','","').split(',').replace('"','')
```

This way You make sure there is a space between every two neighboring quotation marks. With this addition Your approach should work?

Comment: I'm afraid your method just the same as mine https://imgur.com/a/oABJSt https://imgur.com/a/RuX3wZ4, with or without space between two neighbouring quotes

Comment: You edited answer does indeed work, but needs a small tweak `$input=read-host "input"; $input.Replace('""','" "').replace('" "','"|"').split('|').replace('"','')`, instead of using `,` as separator, I'm using `|`, since that's an invalid char in windows for filename.

Comment: :) Yep, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked as expected for me with all possible string combinations, a mix of quoted and not is difficult to handle. Finally gave up and used cmd, since it's geared up to do this exactly. I know that it's a copout but really there should be a commandlet to do this. $input will be an array of all the args.

```
$UninstallString = "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{58C01E5D-F72B-4C0C-8025-E929D6070B6D}\setup.exe`" -runfromtemp -l0x0409  -removeonly"
$input = @(cmd /c "for %i in ($UninstallString) do @echo %~i")

$input.Count
$input
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71513710/6654942 featuring regex `'("[^"]*"|\S)+'`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `-split` and regex:

```bash
$string = '"D:\Path1\file1.txt" "D:\Path2\some [ weird, name.txt""D:\thispath\is_not_separated_by_space_after_quote.txt"'
$string -split '(?<=")\s*(?=")' | ForEach-Object Trim('"')
```

See https://regex101.com/r/lKyxJ0/1 for details.