# Delete an app on windows using powershell without querying win32

Tags: windows, powershell

so I want to delete an app of which I do not know the product ID. I know you can delete an app by using msiexec.exe /x and then the product ID. How would I go about getting the product ID of a specific app also in commandline and storing the value in a variable so I can just place the variable in the delete command?

Thank in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always get-package.  No one knows about it but me.  This should work for msi installs.

```
get-package *software* | uninstall-package
```

If you know the exact name, this should work.  Uninstall-package doesn't take wildcards.

```
uninstall-package 'Citrix HDX RealTime Media Engine 2.9.400'
```

Sometimes, annoyingly, it prompts to install nuget first:

```
install-packageprovider nuget -force
```

If it's not an msi install, but a programs install, it takes a little more string mangling.  You may have to add a '/S' or something for silent install at the end.

```
$prog,$myargs = -split (get-package 'Remote Support Jump Client *' | 
  % { $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] })
& $prog $myargs
```

Maybe in this case just run it:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\Citrix WorkSpace 2202\TrolleyExpress.exe" /uninstall /cleanup /silent
```

Or

```
$uninstall = get-package 'Citrix Workspace 2202' | 
  % { $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] }
$split = $uninstall -split '"'
$prog = $split[1]
$myargs = -split $split[2]
$myargs += '/silent'
& $prog $myargs
```

I think I have a way that works with or without double-quotes for non-msi installs:

```
$uninstall = get-package whatever | % { $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] }
$prog, $myargs = $uninstall | select-string '("[^"]*"|\S)+' -AllMatches | 
  % matches | % value
$prog = $prog -replace '"',$null
$silentoption = '/S'
$myargs += $silentoption  # whatever silent uninstall option
& $prog $myargs
```

Comment: When I execute this one, because this is the package I want to uninstall, I can't. Am I doing something wrong with the name? get-package *Citrix HDX RealTime Media Engine 2.9.400* | uninstall-package

Comment: Names with spaces need to be in quotes.

Comment: How would I go about executing that last command that you've written? because when I give it in powershell I cant execute it

Comment: Copy & paste should work.  $prog would have to be set to something for the last line to work.

Comment: so for Citrix Workspace 2202 this should work?                                                    `$prog,$myargs = -split (get-package 'Citrix Workspace 2202' | 
  % { $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] })
& $prog $myargs`

Comment: It only works if the providername is programs.  Plus you may have to add a silent install option to the end of the arguments.  If it's an msi providername, uninstall-package should work fine.

Comment: Yeah this is the case. The providername is indeed programs :P but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What is `$_.metadata['uninstallstring']` and the package name?

Comment: the package name is Citrix Workspace 2202 and the uninstallstring is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\Citrix WorkSpace 2202\TrolleyExpress.exe" /uninstall /cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I use. You have to know what the display name of the package is...like if  you went to Remove Programs, what it's name would be. It works for my MSI packages that I create with WiX, but not all packages. You might consider `winget` command if you are on Windows 10+. winget has an uninstall option.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $ProductName,
    [switch] $Interactive = $false,
    [switch] $key = $false
)

$log_directory = "c:\users\public"
# $log_directory = "c:\erase\logs"

if ((-not $Interactive) -and (-not (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)))
{
    $interactive = $true
#   echo "Not elevated, needs to be interactive"
}

$found = $null
$productsKeyName = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products"

$rootKey = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($productsKeyName)
foreach ($productKeyName in $rootKey.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    #$productKeyName

    try
    {
        $installPropertiesKey = $rootKey.OpenSubKey("$productKeyName\InstallProperties")

        if ($installPropertiesKey)
        {
            $displayName = [string] $installPropertiesKey.GetValue("DisplayName")
            if ( (! [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($displayName))  -and ($displayName -eq $ProductName))
            {
                $found = $productKeyName
                break
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if ($installPropertiesKey) { $installPropertiesKey.Close() }
    }
}
$rootKey.Close()

if (-not $found)
{
    return "First search could not find $ProductName"
}

$localPackage = $null
if (! [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($found))
{
    try
    {
        $regkey = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("$productsKeyName\$found\InstallProperties")
        $localPackage = $regkey.GetValue("LocalPackage")
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if ($regkey) { $regkey.Close() }
    }
}

if ($key)
{
    return "Found key: $found"
}

if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($localPackage) -and (Test-Path $localPackage))
{
    $logflags = "/lv*"
    $logname = (Join-Path $log_directory "$ProductName_uninstall.log")
    
    
    $args = @($logflags, $logname, "/X", $localPackage)
    if (!$Interactive) { $args += "/q" }
    &msiexec $args
}
else
{
    "Could not find uninstall package: $ProductName"
}
```